# JMeter stops sending JSESSIONID cookie when switched to SSL

Tags: ssl, https, jmeter, session-cookies

I have a test plan that runs fine under http, and the Cookie Manager is correctly keeping my sessions in place.  It is also capable of talking to the same server when switched to ssl, and even thinks everything is working correctly because it gets a 200 response with our custom message about not being logged in.

All I need to do to reproduce the behavior is switch from http to https.  The test is still able to talk to the server, but I can see in the "View Results in Table" log that cookies has a JSESSIONID under http, and is empty under https.  And each request under ssl is answered with a Set-Cookie for JSESSIONID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting scenario.  Does the Jmeter log file offer any clues?

Could it be that Jmeter needs a copy of the certificate to properly store the SSL cookie? The console would display a handshake problem, which can be resolved by adding the certificate into the key store:
http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=210

You might be able to do some further debug by writing out the cookie value to a variable and logging its value:

> Received Cookies can be stored as JMeter thread variables (versions of JMeter after 2.3.2 no longer do this by default). To save cookies as variables, define the property "CookieManager.save.cookies=true". Also, cookies names are prefixed with "COOKIE_" before they are stored (this avoids accidental corruption of local variables) To revert to the original behaviour, define the property "CookieManager.name.prefix= " (one or more spaces). If enabled, the value of a cookie with the name TEST can be referred to as ${COOKIE_TEST}.

Source: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager

Edit: Somebody asked how my specific problem was solved.  It turned out not to have anything to do with ssl specifically, but that other unrelated headers changed very slightly in their format, so the regex we were using to match on them started failing.  So I'd start there with looking at your headers and comparing the difference between when you post http vs https

Comment: Your suggestions turned out to be completely irrelevant, while also being very helpful.  So, thank you.  :) So we can call this an accepted answer, I did find that JMeter has no problem at all with ssl certs, trusted or untrusted.  You pointed me to docs that were tangentially related to the variables problem that was actually causing my troubles.  I won't go into it because they are very specific to our implementation, but it just had to do with a regex that didn't adapt to the extra info that https adds to the set-cookie header.

Comment: Glad my ramblings were of use :)

Comment: Came here for something else, but problem solved. Thanks @BlackGaff :)  +1

Comment: @BrianDeacon .. could you provide some details on how did you fix the issue? I seem to be in a similar scenario. I have recorded a bunch of request for HTTP, but need to switch to https (since the server now has a certificate). I fear I do not want to re-record the scripts, since I have customized them a lot. Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Dexter I added an edit to the question to explain.  It was a long time ago, so I've forgotten some of the specifics.